# Windows virtual microphone in C

Tags: c, windows, api, filtering, portaudio

I asked a similar question a while ago but I didn't know very much, so I wasn't able to be specific enough.

I want to write a program that takes input from my microphone, processes it, and then sends the output to a fake "virtual microphone" as if the processed sound I created was what a microphone was hearing. I would then like to be able to use this virtual microphone with any application that supports choosing your microphone input (pretty much any well written software) as a valid microphone. So what the application "hears" will be my processed version of the microphone input.

I'm working with Portaudio in C and I can capture from the mic, process, and send out to the speakers just fine. Now I need to replace my real speakers in the application with the phony microphone. Windows seems to have some APIs for this. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff536201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
So my sink pin will be the real microphone and I will have to create a NEW source pin that should be visible to other applications. How would I go about doing this? I'm having difficulty finding code samples or really even any very informative documentation.

Language: C
OS: Windows 7

Comment: See [How to create a virtual audio device and stream audio input with it](http://superuser.com/questions/117625/how-to-create-a-virtual-audio-device-and-stream-audio-input-with-it)

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need, and I don't have to do anything with Windows APIs! I'll give this a try, mind putting that in an answer so I can check it?

Comment: On the other hand, it costs a bit more than I would expect. I wouldn't mind doing a bit of programming to save money.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to use the Windows Stereo Mix for that. Then you can open the virtual device in loopback mode and record what the microphone hears with programming

Comment: Wow... Simple, elegant solution with no code required, I like it!

Answer (score 6):

I believe this would require writing a device driver, not merely working with Win32 APIs.

There is a similar question on SuperUser: [How to create a virtual audio device and stream audio input with it](https://superuser.com/questions/117625/how-to-create-a-virtual-audio-device-and-stream-audio-input-with-it).  Their solution is to check out [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm). However it is not free.

There are [alternatives to Virtual Audio Cable](http://alternativeto.net/software/virtual-audio-cable/), one of which being a Windows port of [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/).

Comment: Not exactly the kind of solution I was thinking of, but from reading about Jack, I think it's exactly what I need.

Comment: Sorry for the check-uncheck, but looking further, Jack wouldn't allow me to create a virtual device usable by applications that I don't have the source for.

Comment: I think this is the best answer I'm going to get, so I will re-check.

Answer (score 1):

You could be using the programm called virtual audio cable. The freeware includes up to 3 vac-s. 
Afterward you can use the mitov.com audiolab library to do whatever you want with the sound comming on it. If you want to do some DSP or whatever